# delay or wait 3s then remove class class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$('.class1').delay(3000).not(".class2").removeClass("pulse");
```

It will remove the class before delay!

how can I stop it and delay for 3s and then remove "pulse"?

Comment: Delay delays the animation queue, thus things like fadeIn(), slideUp() or stuff, not removeClass or any other non-queued methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setTimeout()` instead of the delay. That is a regular JS function:

```js
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.class1').not(".class2").removeClass("pulse");
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 3):

`delay()` does not work for `removeClass()` as it does not operate on the queue. You could use `setTimeout()` instead:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.class1:not(.class2)').removeClass('pulse');
}, 3000);
```